# Change status bar content UWP mobile

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to change the status bar on mobiles I want to hide network and wifi and keep clock and change the status background color and add a text on it ..
I already see this on Mspoweruser app and I just don't know how to do it I've find one code and that's code make my app run in full screen but I want to keep clock on the app

Here's my code

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
```

And this a picture from Mspoweruser app status bar
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK they achieved it using `StatusBarProgressIndicator`. With this you don't have to create clock by yourself.

Haven't tested it myself but this should work:

```
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
{
    StatusBar statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
    statusBar.ForegroundColor = YourForegroundColor;
    statusBar.BackgroundColor = YourBackgroundColor;
    statusBar.BackgroundOpacity = 1.0;

    StatusBarProgressIndicator indicator = statusBar.ProgressIndicator;

    indicator.ProgressValue = null; // May not be needed, depends on its default value
    indicator.Text = "Some text shown in status bar";
    await indicator.ShowAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the status bar and create your own time control.

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
{
    await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping hope there's another solution for it